# Comparing two lists from different tables with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to compare two lists extracted from  two different tables

```
var maListe = db.exclure.Where(w => w.type.Contains("Object class"))
                        .GroupBy(g => new {libelle = g.libelle,})
                        .Select(s => new {libellex = s.Key.libelle}).ToList();

var myList = db.Full.Where(c => c.date_reception > new DateTime(2015, 02, 02))
               .Where (c => !maListe.Any(c2 => c2.libellex.Contains(c.mc_object_class)))
               //.Where (p => p.mc_object_class.CompareTo("NULL")<0)
                 .GroupBy(f => new
                    {
                        object_class = f.mc_object_class,
                    })
                 .Select(g => new 
                    { 
                        object_classx = g.Key.object_class, 
                        countx = g.Count() 
                    })
                 .Take(10)
                 .OrderByDescending(o => o.countx)
                 .ToList();
```

I'm looking for elements that exist in `myList` and not in `maListe`, while running the code above I get the following error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Answer (score 1):

You should materialize your collection, something like:

```
var maListe = db.exclure.Where(w => w.type.Contains("Object class"))
                    .GroupBy(g => new {libelle = g.libelle,})
                    .Select(s => new {libellex = s.Key.libelle}).ToList();

var myList = db.Full.Where(c => c.date_reception > new DateTime(2015, 02, 02))
           .AsEnumerable() // database query ends here
           .Where (c => !maListe.Any(c2 => c2.libellex.Contains(c.mc_object_class)))
           //.Where (p => p.mc_object_class.CompareTo("NULL")<0)
             .GroupBy(f => new
                {
                    object_class = f.mc_object_class,
                })
             .Select(g => new 
                { 
                    object_classx = g.Key.object_class, 
                    countx = g.Count() 
                })
             .Take(10)
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.countx)
             .ToList();
```

If you will have time, please, take a look to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738628(v=vs.100).aspx)